# run a python script inside azure datafactory that call APIs using MSI

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

We have a rest API hosted on Azure as a web application which provides a json output when invoked.

Inside datafactory we need to run a databrick activity that have a python code, currently we store the certifications inside the script,  the python script call the URL/web app with the certification and we do the magic.

But we don't want to store the certifications, and we are thinking on using MSI,  is it possible for the python script retrieve the certifications of MSI and call the API?

i thought of having a webapp activity before the databrick activity with MSI and pass it as an input not sure if that a good idea.

any one know how to pass MSI certification to python to use a webapp inside azure?
Referring this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python
but not sure what do i need to get the credentials, the resourceID? an applicationId?

i appreciate if some one has a small script/ example to share =)
thanks guys.